# Clarification about LiveData's strong references in ViewModels

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

The ViewModel [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) quotes:

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

And the LiveData documentation states next:

> LiveData keeps a strong reference to the observer and the owner as long as the given LifecycleOwner is not destroyed. When it is destroyed, LiveData removes references to the observer & the owner.

So, **if we have a LiveData variable defined in a ViewModel**, and we set to observe it using a fragment (or activity) as **owner** and/or **observer**, does this mean that we are breaking the rule stated in the ViewModel documentation? Does the action of setting such type of owner/observer, **indirectly** place an Activity context **reference** within the ViewModel?

By the LiveData documentation seems it shouldn't be a concern as it will take care of removing the references when required, but I would like to know if I am missing something, as seems the documentation is contradicting itself.

Comment: ViewModel and LiveData has different working mechanisms. LifeCycleOwner object is not a View object so the lLİveData references no View object. So there is no problem with the LiveData objects in a ViewModel class. On the other you must not keep a reference to any kind of View object in your ViewModel class like TextView mTextView; setTextView(TextView textView) { mTextView = texView; }. This is what ViewModel documentation means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning to write a post to explain about the issue you asked. But I have not published it. You can read my draft blog in this link: [Exploring LiveData in Android](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_hP1Oj0toxLb-ZIdcYRUGNdYyniOlU4pqtzzRGdoXGg/edit?usp=sharing)

Or short answer for you:
LifecycleOwner: is an interface that has only one method: getLifecyle(). This method returns a Lifecycle object.

Lifecycle: is a class that has states and allows other objects to observe its state changes.

Activity and Fragment: implement LifecycleOwner interface. In the getLifecycle() method, we return a LifecycleRegistry object as Lifecycle. The LifecycleRegister class extends Lifecycle class. This class helps Activity and Fragment notify observers about their state change.

ObserverWrapper is an inner class in LiveData. This class will help LiveData know the state of LifecycleOwner and the latest version of data that the Observer is having.

LifecycleBoundObserver is also an inner class in LiveData. This class extends OberverWrapper to provide LiveData the state of LifecycleOwner and keeps Observer and the data’s version that the Observer is having. It also implements LifecycleEventObserver to observe the Lifecyle’state changes ( in our case, it is Activity’s state and Fragment’s state). This class helps LiveData know the state of Activity (Fragment) and the data version that the Observer is having, so LiveData can decide whether it will notify Activity (Fragment) about an update or not.